# fetch only X Product Model via eager loading in a ManyToMany Product Category relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a ManyToMany relationship between Category and Product Model.

**Product** Model is like this :

```
class Product extends Model
    {
        protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';

        public function categories ()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'category_product', 'product_id', 'cat_id');
        }
}
```

And **Category** Model is :

```
class Category extends Model
        {
            protected $primaryKey = 'cat_id';

            public function products (){
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product','category_product','cat_id','product_id');
        }
    }
```

Now , I want to fetch only last 4(for example) products of each Category. for that I write this :

```
$categories =   Category::with([
    'products'  =>  function($query){
        $query->select('products.product_id')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(4);
    }
])->get();
```

But this does not work properly and return unexpected products count?

How Can I do that?

Comment: You can try with this $categories =   Category::all();
foreach($categories as $category) {
    $latestProduct = $category->products()->orderBy('product_id','DESC')->skip(0)->take(4)->get();
} Change the class name of Category  model in question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last X number of products per category you can try something like :

```
Category::with(['products' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('updated_at','desc')->take(X);
}])->get();
```

This should return a Collection of Categories in which you should have no more than the desired number of products per category.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Not exactly, since you're having a Many to Many relationship  the callback is exectued on the pivot table (ie. category_product). In your code, you were trying to select the product_id of the products table (even though you probably meant the categories table).

Comment: I try your code and for `take(2)` it return similar results and for only two Category return related products . I select only `product_id` from products beacause I do not need to other fields of Product.